# What happens when submitting an html form? (the process behind the scenes)

Tags: html, forms

Can someone please tell me what happens behind the scenes in the following case (i.e. explain the whole technical process)?

```
<form method="get" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="d" value="flowers">
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

In this case after one has clicks on “send” a new webpage opens saying: "You have searched for "flowers" " and an image of some flowers below.

In the browser tab right after the URL of the newly opened page there is 
“/?s=flowers”. What is that?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Into what detail do you expect us to get here? What exactly is what you're not understanding?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Sure, it could use some clarification, but he's asked a legitimate question for someone just starting to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click Send, the page data specified in the form information and values is passed to the server via HTTP.

The `/?s=flowers` is the GET data being passed back to the server.  Although, based on the form code you've provided, the "name" of that value is `d`.  So the URL would actually have `/?d=flowers`

The PHP or server side language then handles that information to do specific tasks.  It can access the info using the name "d". This method of sending data is called `GET`, there are also other ways of doing this. The most common, `POST`, does not display the data in the URL and send the data through HTTP headers.

The code you've shown has an action of "#" which means the HTTP method is being sent the same page.  Meaning this page code would have some PHP located in it.  This can also be done by using a seperate file, such as `action='send.php'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would like to ask, what exatcly do you mean by "It can access the info using the name "d"." ?

Comment: PHP would get the value of "d" by using the variable `$_GET['d']` and that variable would be equal to "flowers", in this case.